# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT issue

Tags: dns, internet, streaming

I have this annoying error that appears when I try to reach websites while streaming on Twitch or Hitbox using OBS/Xsplit.

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT appears for every website I try to reach only when I am live on Hitbox or Twitch.
As soon as I close the stream program, everything is back to normal.

Sometimes I can reach the websites but they are very slow and elements are missing, such as images, etc. I have to refresh several times and wait a couple of seconds to finally reach a website. 
And as I said, this only happends when I'm live streaming.

I am using Windows 7 64bit, Google Chrome (the problem occurs with Firefox too). I use Wifi but as a test I directly connected a PC on Ethernet on the modem itself and the problem occurs too. Here's my set up: I have a modem/router with the router function ON. I've linked to it (with Ethernet) a Wifi router with router function OFF so it works as an AP). So when this ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error appears while I'm streaming, this error appears both on the wirelessly connected devices and on the devices directly connected to the main modem/router with Ethernet.

Edit 1: I've noticed that the ping on my online game doesn't get higher, I always get about 20 ms.

Edit 2: Here is a test of ICSI Netalyzr I have made right now, when the problem occurs (I am live streaming at the moment, that's why the problem is happening now):
[image]

What could it be ?

Comment: Simply it is because you are streaming. Streaming takes up a huge amount of bandwidth. You could speak to your ISP about getting a faster connection. If you are streaming professionally you may want to consider a business line to your home.

Comment: I don't think this is due to bandwidth. I have a 80 down and 20 up mbps connection and the streaming software only uses 2 mbps upload (I set the bitrate to 2000 kbps on OBS or Xsplit). Believe me, this is not a bandwidth problem as I can download or even upload torrents, etc at the same time and it works really well. But the only thing that doesn't work is reaching simple websites. They are not slow because of my bandwidth, they are slow or inaccessible because something is wrong maybe with the DNS ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS or the method you are connecting to the with (wifi or ethernet)? The bandwidth bottleneck might be occurring between your PC and router, not out to the internet. Especially if you share the connection with other people.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64bit, Google Chrome (the problem occurs with Firefox too). I use Wifi but as a test I directly connected a PC on Ethernet on the modem itself and the problem occurs too. 

Here's my set up: 
I have a modem/router with the router function ON. I've linked to it (with Ethernet) a Wifi router with router function OFF so it works as an AP). So when this ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error appears while I'm streaming, this error appears both on the wirelessly connected devices and on the devices directly connected to the main modem/router with Ethernet.

Comment: The error you are getting doesn't suggest issues with DNS. Do you have any evidence to support your theory?

Comment: Not really. What made me think about DNS was because I used to have DNS issues a while ago but it was fixed so I instinctively thought about DNS. 
But you're right, something tells me that it's not a DNS issue because I also changed the DNS of my modem/router to OpenDNS and the problem appeared as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39384/discussion-between-burgi-and-radipacuit).

Comment: Run http://www.pingtest.net/ with both the streaming on and off, and post both results here.

Comment: Here are the results with streaming on:
-Packet loss: 0%
-Ping: 21 ms
-Jitter: 9ms
-Grade A

I guess with streaming OFF results are the same or better. That's weird, I don't get it. Why are the results so good ? (maybe because pingtest selected a close server ?)